# Compressed Sparse Row Matrix :: csr_matrix :: odd behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, sparse-matrix

I've been observing some odd behaviour in my code that's been troubling me. The following...

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
A = csr_matrix([[1,2,0],[0,0,3],[4,0,5]])
B = A
B[0,0] = 99
```

I would expect `A.toarray()` to return the original matrix (with no updated 99 value), however I actually get this

```
A.toarray()

Out:
array([[99,  2,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  3],
       [ 4,  0,  5]], dtype=int32)
```

What's going on?

Comment: `A` and `B` are pointers to the same object in memory. `A is B` should return True. Use the method `id(obj)` to get the memory address of the object. The results of `id(A)` and `id(B)` should be the same.

Comment: That doesn't seem to hinge on A being a sparse matrix. You'll see this behaviour with any container type. B=A assigns a reference to the same object to B. Since these are changed in-place `B[0,0]=` and `A[0,0]=` are exactly equivalent here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statement `b = a` gives `b` the same reference as `a`.

i.e., they both refer to the same object in memory.

Any changes made to one will obviously be reflected in the other as they are the SAME and not just equal.

Instead, use `b=a.copy()`. This passes into `b` a copy of `a`.